# Ionic 2 / 3 + Firebase + signInWithPhoneNumber

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am a new programmer, so I may ask very easy questions but I couldn't find the answer by myself.

I have been able to create an app that combines: Ionic 2 / 3 and Firebase to create a user and validate it via mobile number (`signInWithPhoneNumber` and a `reCaptcha`).
This works perfectly in the browser but not on the device because of the `reCaptcha` (it only work on browsers!!).
I tried several thing but not working:

1. Search for a `npm` package that solves the issue. I couldn't find one. No one has found a solution?
2. Trying to store a valid `reCaptcha` value and use it always to "cheat on Firebase". I tried to store a valid one locally, but I couldn't because it is a circular variable. Can anyone help me with this option?

I tried to find a simple solution, since I dont want to program 2 apps, one for iOS and one for Android since I am not that good at programming.

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773475/1783706